# expo standalone app background fetch not starting task automatically in iPad

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, background-fetch, react-native-background-fetch

I am developing a expo react native standalone app .
I am integating a expo background fetch in my mobile app project.
I writing a code to start a background task every minute it's working properly in the android.
if I am trying with iPad with the below configuration and code , it's not executing a task automatically.
Can some one help on this?

Config changes in app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["location", "fetch"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code for component

```
const triggerBackgroundFetch = async (taskName: string, taskFn: TaskManagerTaskExecutor, interval: number = 60 * 1) => {
  try {
    if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(taskName)) {
      console.log('new task')
      TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, taskFn);
    }
    else {
      console.log('existing task')
    }
    const options = {
      minimumInterval: interval // in seconds
    };
    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, options);
    await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(60);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("registerTaskAsync() failed:", err);
  }
}

const executeBackgroundTask = () => {
  try {
    // fetch data here...
    const backendData = "task run time " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
    Alert.alert("Bg task")
    console.log("Background Task: ", backendData);
    //@ts-ignore
    setStateFn(backendData);
    return backendData
      ? BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData
      : BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NoData;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err')
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;
  }
}

  const triggerTask = async () => {
    console.log('trigger background fetch')
    await triggerBackgroundFetch('BackgroundTask1', executeBackgroundTask, 60);
   // await unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync('PushNotificationBackgroundTask3');
  };
```

[image]

iOS : 15.6.1

I am trying expo background fetch in the expo standalone app at iPad using windows machine.
I am expecting to trigger a background fetch task automatically every interval.